# Dictates what happens when a user 'goes back' (via browser button) from a Visualforce app

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, app

I have a visualforce app that takes an input and then displays a table of information from that input (via an external call in a connected controller).

There is an issue where if a user tries to use the browsers back button whilst 'inside' the app, after the input is received and the table is being shown, will unload/crash - see below. This only happens if the user has the app open/selected, as clicking off the app onto the page then going back will function as normal.

[image: Crash Screen]

Is there anyway I can add a JavaScript or Controller Method to trigger when this happens instead or at least prevent this message being shown to the user.

Happy to try any suggestions and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard HTML "form" behavior. In order to eliminate the problem, you need to use client-side rendering. I wrote up a very short example that demonstrates how you can implement this.

```
<apex:page controller="historyExample" docType="html-5.0">
    <script>
    function handlePopState(event) {
        setHistoryValue(event.state.value);
    }
    function updateState(event) {
        const { value } = event.target;
        history.pushState({ value }, '', `?value=${value}`);
        setHistoryValue(value);
    }
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
    </script>
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:input label="Enter Number" type="number" value="{!historyNumber}" onchange="updateState(event)"></apex:input>
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!updateHistoryNumber}" reRender="form" name="setHistoryValue">
            <apex:param name="newNumber" assignTo="{!newNumber}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

```
public class historyExample {
    public Integer historyNumber { get; set; }
    public static Integer newNumber { get;  set; }
    public void updateHistoryNumber() {
        historyNumber = newNumber;
    }
    
}
```

Here, we have the value to store `historyNumber` and an input parameter `newNumber`.  We use an `apex:actionFunction` to update the page state whenever we want to recover from the back button or when creating new entries in history.  I used `?` for a query string, but you could also use a `#` anchor fragment to display this data.

Since a server call is involved, make sure you keep your state setting function (here, `updateHistoryNumber`) as small and fast as possible, and try to render only as much as you need to.

This is a solution that involves the Visualforce View State; you may decide to just write a Lightning Web Component or Aura Component and load that, instead. A pure client-side solution would perform far better. You can use `@RemoteAction` functions if you need to interact with the server.

Comment: Hello Fox, thanks for you help and pointing out the underlying issue. I did some research into the top and realized that my page wasn't caching as the apex page was set to "<apex:page  cache="false">" - i changed this to cache="true" and going back now goes back a step rather than crashing the app. Thanks very much.